# Importing Excel data into multiple SQL tables

Tags: php, sql, excel, import

I have an excel document that I need to import into SQL. I have 3 existing SQL tables: account, account_type, and sub_type. For each row in the excel, I need to insert a new row into account, with a foreign key linking to a new row in the account_type, with a foreign key linking to a new row in sub_type.

So account links to account_type links to sub_type. Each row of the excel sheet has data that will populate the three different tables.

I am thinking there should be a way to do this with some kind of loop in the query where I can get the last inserted ids and all that jazz, but my SQL knowledge isn't to the point of loops and functions and all that advanced stuff.

Appreciate any help on how to sort this out!

edit: Using MSSQL server. I am trying to get it all done in one sql query.

Comment: Do you have a question or are you looking for someone who is doing your work for you?

Comment: And PDO for SQL. PDO have a function "lastInsertId" to get last the last id.

Comment: I have no problem doing my own work. I have been at this for hours and need help. The question is what kind of sql statement do I need to get this to work.

Comment: Dagon, I will check that out, thanks. Duffy, PDO is just a way to connect to a db, right? I am aware of how to get the last inserted id through a regular php query. The area I am having trouble with is working with the excel file. Is there a way to do this with only SQL queries?

Comment: What database system are you using (SQL Server, MySql, Oracle...)? SQL is only a language not a database product. And what you are asking is **very** vendor specific.

Comment: Maybe you can generate a CSV file from Excel and create some function that loop this file and insert in database.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, I am using MSSQL server.